# export SO careers CV as a PDF

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

How do I export my SO Careers CV as a PDF file?

I used to be able to do this by clicking on the print button, but now this gives me a 404.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The direct link of the PDF is `https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/pdf/{user ID}?View=Pdf`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/pdf/247702?View=Pdf

You can reach this page by going to your profile, clicking the *Developer Story* tab and clicking the *Save as PDF* button.

> [image: screenshot of how to navigate to the PDF]

Comment: Where can we go to hide/unhide parts of our CV before saving it to PDF? This used to be possible in the old version of SO careers, I believe.

Comment: @ScottCoates No idea, sorry. Not sure if it's still possible.

Comment: @ScottCoates did you ever find it?

Comment: @ScottCoates I downloaded the HTML of my resume from the preview, edited my sections and exported a PDF using system printer.